# Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I am a beginner to Hibernate and I'm having a trouble making it work. I am working MSsql server 2008. I am getting the error:

```
"Failed to create sessionFactory
object.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider"
```

at the line:

```
factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

I am using the below mentioned Jars:

```
lib/antlr.jar   lib/cglib.jar   lib/asm.jar  
lib/commons-collections.jar   lib/commons-logging.jar   lib/jta.jar  
lib/dom4j.jar   lib/log4j.jar   lib/hibernate3.jar
```

Please help me out. I searched for MetadataProvider and have put that too but still no output

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the jar named hibernate-common-annotations

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.2.0.Final